# How to programmatically close the native outgoing call UI?

Tags: android, gsm

I'm trying to intercept outgoing calls so that I can give the user the choice to use SIM or VOIP to make the call.
I'm intercepting outgoing calls using a filter on "NEW_OUTGOING_CALL". This is working fine and I can show a dialog asking how they want the call to be completed but I still get the outgoing call UI showing. Is there a way to kill this UI off, or should I just make my choice dialog full screen (but that would look horrible) or is there another approach anyone can recommend.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you preventing the outgoing call from taking place? According to the docs, you have to return `null` in the resultData. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that, I also do a stopCall()